# Parameters in route are not resolved

Tags: ruby, padrino

I have this configuration in the controller in Padrino

```
MyProject::App.controllers do
  get '/'  do
    handlebars :index
  end

  get :file, :with => :tokenId   do
    tokenId = params[:tokenId]

    [extra logic]
  end
end
```

GET / works.

GET /file/abc doesn't.

GET /file/:tokenId works!

It looks like `:token` is not recognized as a parameter placeholder in the route definition.

I've tried

```
get "/file/:tokenId"
```

too but with no luck.

I can't find any information on any similar issue, anybody can help? Happy to add more information if needed.

Comment: camelCase is not the ruby way try `token_id`

Comment: it works! Create an answer and I'll pick it as the solution. Also I should add that that controller is being ported from Sinatra, where that routing worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I am unsure why the change made a difference but camelCase is generally considered poor syntax for variables in ruby.(Padrino may be calling a method such as underscore on your variable i.e.

```
"tokenID".underscore.to_sym 
#=>:token_id
```

Using underscored_variables instead. (e.g. `:tokenID` becomes `:token_id`. This structure also allows for interacting with databases in a nicer way as well since your columns will have names such as `token_id` not `tokenID`.

There are uses for camelCasing in ruby and rails such as `class` naming and `generators` but trying keep all local and instance variables in lowercase underscore format.

I don't do much work in `padrino` so I am not 100% sure why this change helped but I am glad I could help.